# Firefox kerning differently to other browsers (negative letter spacing in CSS)

Tags: css, firefox, typography

I am having issues with Firefox rendering text differently to every other browser when negative letter spacing is applied:

```
h2{font-size:1.6em;font-weight:bold;color:#999;letter-spacing:-0.10em;}

<h2>Time</h2>(approx)
```

Here is the text rendered in most browsers: http://img707.imageshack.us/i/font2x.png/

Here is the text rendered in Firefox: http://img444.imageshack.us/i/font1.png/

**Edit: They are direct screenshots, the images are the same resolution.**

Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Comment: You posted the same link twice :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why, but if you use `pt` instead `em` in your `font-size` declaration (but keep `em` for `letter-spacing`, Firefox should render your text as the other browsers do.

```
h2{font-size:18pt;font-weight:bold;color:#999;letter-spacing:-0.10em;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the declaration `width: 100%;` to the `h2` rule to trigger layout in the "other" browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I got it fixed by resetting the css. Just add the below link to your html head.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/reset/reset-min.css">
```

More information can be found here. http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/